# This is simple Abstraction demo code where i am not able to create a object of suresh class can someone help me out what is going wrong here

Tags: java

This is simple Abstraction demo code where i am not able to create a object of suresh class can someone help me out what is going wrong here

```
public class AbstractionDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Mahesh obj= new Suresh();
        obj.call();
        obj.cook();
        obj.dance();
        obj.move();
    }


    abstract class Mahesh{

        public void call()
        {
            System.out.println("Calling");
        }

        public  abstract  void move();
        public  abstract  void dance();
        public  abstract  void cook();

    }


    abstract class Ramesh extends Mahesh {

        public void move()
        {
            System.out.println("Moving");
        }
    }



    class Suresh extends Ramesh{
        public void dance()
        {
            System.out.println("dancing");

        }

        public void cook()
        {
            System.out.println("Cooking");
        }
    }
}
```

At `Mahesh obj= new Suresh();` I am getting below error

> No enclosing instance of type AbstractionDemo is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type AbstractionDemo (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of AbstractionDemo)

[image]

Comment: Please include the error message you're getting as text in the body of your question, not as an image.

Comment: Hover over the swiggly line and see what it says

Comment: getting below error"No enclosing instance of type AbstractionDemo is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type AbstractionDemo (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of AbstractionDemo)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create an inner class object without creating an instance of outer class. Read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)

```
Suresh obj = new AbstractionDemo().new Suresh();
obj.dance(); // Whatever methods you have
```

Comment: by taking suresh ramesh and mahesh classes out of main i can do right?

Comment: Yes by taking suresh ramesh and mahesh classes out of  AbstractionDemo  you don't need an instance of AbstractionDemo

Comment: @SiddheshRaut, put these suresh mahesh classes into separate classes. Since you only want to demo the abstract class behavior and not inner class functinonality.